# Django formatting multiple times

Tags: django

Using the default delta time field for Django, but as most know it returns horrifically. So I have developed my own function, `convert_timedelta(duration)`. It computes days, hours, minutes and seconds, just like you might find on this website. It works like a charm on a single time ( I.e. when I was calculating an average time for one specific column ) .. However now I'm modifying how this works so it returns multiple times for a column... Separating times returned grouped by their ID, rather than just having one set time returned. So now I have multiple times returned, which works fine with the default formatting. But when I apply it to my function it doesn't like it and no particular informative errors are alerted.

```
def convert_timedelta(duration):
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (seconds % 60)
```

Comment: That function doesn't return anything...

Comment: returns hours, minutes, seconds... the function itself works - it works on one time format but as soon as two or more is returned it breaks @Sayse

Comment: @PaulT is this the full function? Where's the return statement? What error specifically are you seeing?